# Creating new Managed metadata service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, managed-metadata

I want to create a new Service Application of type managed metadata.
But I do not know what I should provide in the following fields in ad new metadata service dialog box:-

1. **Database name** .  should/can I define the database name to an already existing DB “SharePoint_config” Or I should create new database name.
2. For defining the application pool name. I have already create an application pool user named SPS_Farm . but I do not know what I should provide for the **Application pool name** filed , can I use any name ??

Thanks & Regards

Comment: My tip is to create a new database and use the existing app poll you use for services. If you do not know the name of that you can check it on another service applications properties, or look in IIS

Comment: thanks for the reply. currently I have two service "Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application" and "Security Token Service Application ". But for both of them the properties icon is disabled , so I can not get the name of the current application pool
.

Comment: Then look in IIS or just create a new one to use with your service applications. Make sure to use your app pool account

Comment: Thanks it worked well, but since i am doing this work on my development  environment. So is there a way to efficiently move these sort of work from environment to another . Or i have to manually re-create these service application in the staging or production environments again ?

Comment: You would have to recreate them or backup / restore them